# i got an error while running a python script using the code generated by selenium ide browser extension and i have no clue how to resolve this issue

Tags: python, selenium

this is the error message.
it appeared in a red coloured background box.
i ran it in visual studio code.
i have no clue what to do and i have no understanding what this error message means.

the goal was to run the automation software to automate some actions in chrome.
i have the correct chromedriver version.

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#mat-option-165 .pr-2:nth-child(1)"}
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.67)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8B8F3+2406643]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E1AF31+1945393]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D0C748+837448]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D392E0+1020640]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D3957B+1021307]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D66372+1205106]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D542C4+1131204]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D64682+1197698]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D54096+1130646]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2E636+976438]
    Ordinal0 [0x00D2F546+980294]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010F9612+2498066]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010EC920+2445600]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F24F2A+579370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00F23D36+574774]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E21C0B+1973259]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E26688+1992328]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E26775+1992565]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E2F8D1+2029777]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x761BFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A47A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A47A4E+238]
  File "C:\Users\Public\Untitled-2.py", line 38, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mat-option-165 .pr-2:nth-child(1)").click()
```

here is the code that led up to the error message.
the code between the "#####" and "###" are copied from the file generated by the selenium ide.
the last line of the code is what causes the error message.

```
#####
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
###

from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.travelstart.co.za")


  
#####
driver.get("https://www.travelstart.co.za/")
driver.set_window_size(1552, 840)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "dept_city0").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "dept_city0").send_keys("cpt")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".sub_txt:nth-child(6)").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "arr_city0").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "arr_city0").send_keys("jnb")
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#mat-option-165 .pr-2:nth-child(1)").click()
###
```

i am using python 3.10.4

Comment: As the error says `Unable to locate element` it means that the element `"#mat-option-165 .pr-2:nth-child(1)"` was not found in the webpage. I tried and once arrived at the last line of code, there is no `#mat-option-165` in the webpage but there are others ending with 131, 132 and 133 instead of 165

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.